# How to get Data from Many-2-Many-Relation an ObjectBricks

Tags: twig, many-to-many, pimcore

When creating templates for document output, I would like to access the fields of ObjectBricks or many2many relations. With the relations, I can only access the path of the relation via Twig, but not the content of the object.
With ObjectBricks I can't get any further via Twig. I understood that all objects that are addressed in a class are loaded.
Or do I have to create extra snippets or views for each object, which are then included in the template? This then again in PHP and not in Twig?

Example :
a product has a m2m relation to a class "Material" , which contains the field "Description".

```
{% set matdate = product.Material %}
{% if matdate %}                     
    {% for element in matdat %}
        
            {{ element }}
```

so far it works, but

```
{% if(item) %}
    {% for dat in element %}
        
           {{dat}}
        
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

When I then address the array, I get no content and no error.

Unfortunately, the descriptions from the Pimcore documentation don't help me with the ObjectBricks either. I can't figure out how to query them.

Maybe it's just a problem of understanding that is clear to everyone, but I can't find an answer.

---

Here is the dump:

```
      Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\ElementMetadata {#4103 ▼
      #elementType: "object"
      #elementId: "88"
      #fieldname: "Material"
      #columns: array:1 [▶]
      #data: []
      #dao: Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Data\ElementMetadata\Dao {#4078 ▶}
      #_owner: Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Implantat {#4079 ▶}
      #_fieldname: "Material"
      #_language: null
      elementType: "object"
      elementId: "88"
      fieldname: "Material"
      columns: array:1 [▶]
      data: []
      _owner: Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Implantat {#4079 ▶}
  _fieldname: "Material"
  _language: null
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem. Also, in the first snippet there is no variable `elements` only `element`. In your second snippet there is no variable `date`. What is not working? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Sorry, there was a copy & paste error.
I edited the snippets.

To the fields of relation,
I only get the path to the relation. I understood it in such a way that the object returns an array (here element), which I can then read out in the loop, i.e. each dat in element.

Comment: You can try to do `{{ dump(dat) }}` if debug is enabled

Comment: Thanks, dump(dat) doesn't work, but dump(element) brings me everything to the product object. That's interesting, but not what I want. I actually wanted the object that is listed in the relation.